# How to avoid google-analytics-loading delaying load event listener when offline

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

I have an app which works both online and offline. I have included GA in the body with async on. I also have core functions dealing with DOM associated with `load` event listener on `window`. When the system is not connected, the ga.js file takes a lot of time to try to load. This prevents the `load` event from firing. So how can I avoid this situation? I can use `DOMContentLoaded` but that would be the same thing because js files are included in DOM content.

Comment: possible duplicate of [If Google Analytics goes down, how do I keep my site working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413271/if-google-analytics-goes-down-how-do-i-keep-my-site-working)

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try.

1. We allow ga to load normally.
2. We store a reference to ga dom element in a global variable (gaClone).
3. We set a timeout of 30seconds. We also set another global variable (loadedGoogleAnalytics) and set it to 0 initially. When ga loads, we set this variable to 1. On the timeout expiry, we check whether ga was loaded or not. If not, we delete the dom element ga.

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       var loadedGoogleAnalytics = 0;
       var gaClone;
       var _gaq = _gaq || [];
       _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-123456789-1']);
       _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

       _gaq.push(function() {
           loadedGoogleAnalytics = 1;
           //console.log('GA Actualy executed!');
       });

       (function() {
           var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
           ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
           var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);

           gaClone = ga;

       })();

       setTimeout(function() {
           //console.log('timeout fired');
           if (loadedGoogleAnalytics != 1) {
               gaClone.parentNode.removeChild(gaClone); 
           }
       }, 30000);
   </script>
   ```

Comment: But that would mean the app would still be stalling for 30 seconds. 30 seconds is too much. I think it won't be good UX to keep user waiting for 30 seconds because he/she is offline. If we reduce the number, then we risk removing a valid (albeit slow) gs.js load. Isn't there any way to make an exception for ga.js to not be included for load event to be fired?