# How does google analytics send event tracking data to their server?

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I opened Firefox console and run this:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'Gone With the Wind']);
```

Event is tracked and is inside google analytics, but when I run this inside console it didn't showed any ajax request. How is this possible? How does google analytics send event tracking data to their server? Does it impact site performance if there is too many events?

Comment: Have a look at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide

Comment: I checked this before but didn't find answer to my question.

Comment: Just found answer. It uses gif image to send data. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343153/why-does-google-analytics-use-a-one-pixel-picture-to-transfer-data)

Comment: This is a good explanation: http://mrcoles.com/blog/google-analytics-asynchronous-tracking-how-it-work/